# Break loop on greater number then unsigned long long

Tags: c++, c

I have n of `type unsigned long long` 
and a loop in c/c++

```
while( n < ULLONG_MAX ){
...
n += revert( n );
}
```

I need to output the last n before it goes really big, is there a way I can verify and break loop? Because all the time I get outputted big same number but less then ULLONG_MAX

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `n` is `unsigned long long` then `n <= ULLONG_MAX` is always true.

If you know that `revert` always returns a positive number you can check if `n + revert( n )` is `< n` (i.e., check a wrap around). Or also check that `revert(n) < ULLONG_MAX - n`.

Comment: `n < ULLONG_MAX` is not true for `n = ULLONG_MAX` ;-)

Comment: I would suggest using a different formulation. `n <= ULLONG_MAX` is an obvious (rather useless) statement. The point is, that `while ( n < ULLONG_MAX )` will only break for exactly one value which differs from the intended behaviour

Comment: The `n < ULLONG_MAX` makes me think the OP either assumes `n + positive_integer` will saturate to `ULLONG_MAX` when the result is not representable in an `unsigned long long` or that `n + positive_integer` can be `> ULLONG_MAX`.

Comment: Tnx, good point really. But in my function revert and in loop I've used division by 10: as `(float) n/10` and comparing with `(float)ULLONG_MAX/10`

Comment: Be careful if you use `float` in place of `unsigned long long` than not all `unsigned long long ` values can be represented precisely in a  `float`. For example `16777217` will be stored as `16777216.0` in a IEEE-754 float.

Comment: I just thought of such checking before reverse operation or just summing, using it to compare only

Answer (score 1):

You'll never be able to output a number larger than `ULLONG_MAX` using a `unsigned long long` to store your value.

If you are lucky your function `revert` will get you exactly the same value of `n` as `ULLONG_MAX` (`std::numeric_limits<unsigned long long>::max ()`) but trying to go any higher will just wrap the value around starting from zero (what is known as a *integer overflow*)..

You could do something like the below to check for wrapping:

```
if (n > (n + revert (n)))
  break; // max of 'n += revert (n)' found
```

<sup>the above requires that 'revert' always returns a positive number, of course</sup>